# update single value in EF 4.0

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

i m working on MVC application and using Entity Framework 4.0 for database connection.While editing record i want to update some fields in table. code for edit is

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProjectActivityDetail projectactivitydetail, FormCollection formcollection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string value = Request["ChkIntBool"];
            if (value.Substring(0, 4) == "true") { projectactivitydetail.IsApproved = 1; } else { projectactivitydetail.IsApproved = 0; }
            projectactivitydetail.ProjectActivityDID = long.Parse(Session["ProjectActivityDID"].ToString());
            projectactivitydetail.UpatedBy = long.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString());
            projectactivitydetail.UpdatedON = System.DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(projectactivitydetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FK_ProjectActivityID = new SelectList(db.ProjectActivityMasters, "ProjectActivityID", "ActivityName", projectactivitydetail.FK_ProjectActivityID);
        return View(projectactivitydetail);
    }
```

i just want to update these fields but when this executred my other fields updated to null , is there any way i can keep those values as it is and update these many values in database table.please help

Comment: When you debug the code, does your object contain the non-null values (i.e. when the object is passed into the method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the entity being passed into the service call is not complete. My advice would be to find the existing entity and make the changes to that rather than attaching the one passed in:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProjectActivityDetail projectactivitydetail, FormCollection formcollection)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //I'm assuming the PK of the entity is id so adjust for that
        var entity = db.Set<ProjectActivityDetail>().Find(projectactivitydetail.id);
        string value = Request["ChkIntBool"];
        entity.IsApproved = value.Substring(0, 4) == "true" ? 1 : 0;
        entity.ProjectActivityDID = long.Parse(Session["ProjectActivityDID"].ToString());
        entity.UpatedBy = long.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString());
        entity.UpdatedON = System.DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.FK_ProjectActivityID = new SelectList(db.ProjectActivityMasters, "ProjectActivityID", "ActivityName", projectactivitydetail.FK_ProjectActivityID);
    return View(projectactivitydetail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way. Add hidden fields to your view with the data you want to persist on the model, int this case `ProjectActivityDetail`, this way the properties will get bound to the `projectactivitydetail` variable on the model binding stage.

Suppose you have a property called `CreatedOn` that is being set to null, on your view you'd add:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
```

Then, when you submit the form the value originally on `CreatedOn` will be bound to the property at `projectactivitydetail` and your model will be saved just fine. Your fields are being updated to null because model binding is not finding any values for them.

Good luck.